# FTP directory with permissions d --- --- ---

Tags: permissions, ftp

I uploaded a wordpress theme onto a wordpress installation on a site hosted at godaddy. I used gFTP on an ubuntu machine for the transfer. Now I'm in a situation where I cannot view the contents of the folder, can't reset its permissions, or delete it. I get a "permission denied" on every single attempt to change anything about it. The permissions in gFTP for the folder are being shown as

```
d --- --- ---
```

The owner of the directory is the same as all the other folders (a static 5 thousand something number). But if the owner is the same, he should be allowed to alter permissions, right? What is a way out? Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any permissions on that directory...you'll need root-access to change the permissions, I'm afraid.

Comment: On Linux, a file's owner is always allowed to change its permissions (unless file is set to "immutable" or similar, which can only be done by root himself)

Comment: @grawity: Oh, I always thought 'not-readable' does also mean 'don't touchable'. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @grawity: So, since the directory in question has the same owner as that of other directories.. (which I've assumed to be the only FTP user configured on the system), and I can make modifications to them, why can I not change permissions if the owner has the ability to do that? Any idea?

@Bobby: Thank you. I had to 'upgrade' the account to gain the SSH service for root access, which involves a day's wait. I'll post an update about the outcome asap.